# conditional deletion of lines in xml file using sed

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

This question may not have a straight forward answer... if so, not to worry. I have an XML file that looks something like

```
<a>0.00</a>
<b>0.00</b>
<c>0.00</c>
<d>0.00</d>
```

This is a dumbed down version of what i'm working with. My goal is to delete any line with a data point of zero, if and only if all data points are zero (as the example i've given above). Even if one of the lines in the file contains a non zero entry, i can't delete any of them. For example if the above was

```
<a>0.00</a>
<b>0.00</b>
<c>1.00</c>
<d>0.00</d>
```

then the file should remain untouched. Ultimately, I only want to delete all lines if they all have zero in each and every tag, and leave the file as is otherwise. I know the following will work if all lines have a zero data entry.

```
sed --in-place '\|>0.00</|d' $FILENAME
```

However, if I have the second example below, this will leave me with

```
<c>1.00</c>
```

which isn't what I'm looking for. I know I probably need an if statement, something like

```
if (all lines contain the string '>0.00</') then
   sed --in-place '\|>0.00</|d' $FILENAME 
fi
```

I suppose its the condition in the if statement that i'm not sure about. How would I go about stating "if all lines contain the above mentioned string"? I dont necessarily have to use sed, I have used awk in the past, but I am most comfortable with sed.... Any input or pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The answer you are looking for is to not use sed. You want to use something that can understand XML. Either XSLT or a perl, python, ruby, etc. and a loop over your elements or possibly even just something that can do XPath selectors. But anything purely text-based is going to make this more complicated.

Comment: I had a feeling that was going to be the answer... Many thanks for the prompt response nevertheless.

Comment: If your input is sufficiently constrained and regular you *can* get a pure-text solution to work but just about *any* deviation is going to (at least potentially) break it.

Comment: unfortunately, this file can and will take any of the forms mentioned in the original post so it will definitely deviate - and consequently "break" it. I will need to investigate a different route to take I think. Thanks for the input.

Comment: In this case deviation is more about the xml contents and less about the data itself. Meaning if you can assert that you will always and only ever have lines that look exactly like that (whatever the element contents are) and that those will be the only xml elements in the parent element (or whatever) then you can do this with awk/etc. But XSLT/xmlstarlet/scripting is a much safer solution.

Comment: Ah, i misinterpreted your last comment so. I'm 100% certain that the child elements will always be the same for the parent element in question. The only thing that will change is the actual data. The latter is actually coming from a PostgreSQL database, so I'm now thinking of writing a trigger on the associated table to hopefully do the same thing as I mentioned above. As you correctly pointed out, sed probably isn't the way to go with this problem. I would be curious to see a solution using awk, but I think I'll focus on writing an SQL trigger for now.

Comment: this is a bit confuse about "then the file should remain untouched" because you could put anything behind this that does not allow to select data to check. Some assumption could be used to limit the scpe like only list with a 1 letter tag , a number (which kind is allowed ?) and the closing tag corresponding to the first one are treated ... without this, how to validate a `<foo>bar</foo> as a non "0" or data to filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -vq ">0.00<" $FILENAME || sed -i '\|>0.00<|d' $FILENAME
```

Second command gets executed only file contains 0.00 in all lines.

Comment: Wow!! This is so simple and works absolutely perfectly... Its exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you